# Esp and blynk app

Tags: relay, blynk

It is possible to control one relay using Blynk app and also using an atmega? To a better understanding think at a relay that will turn on a fan when you use the blynk app. but when you don;t have the phone around you, using a pushbutton, you can turn it on from there(the button will be connected to atmega)

---

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(relCh1,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(relCh2,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(relCh3,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(relCh4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relCh1,HIGH);
  pinMode(EspReadPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(relCh3,HIGH);
}
void loop()
{
Serial.println(digitalRead(6));
delay(400);
  if(digitalRead(EspReadPin == 1))
  {
    digitalWrite(relCh3,LOW);
  }
  else if(digitalRead(EspReadPin == 0))
  {
    digitalWrite(relCh3,HIGH);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Use [the Blynk example sketch](https://examples.blynk.cc/?board=ESP8266&shield=ESP8266%20WiFi&example=GettingStarted%2FVirtualPinWrite) to activate the pin of the esp8266. Read the pin of the esp8266 with the ATMega. Handle in ATmega sketch the esp8266 pin as a second button.

Comment: i can't understand. Can you please to explain more detailed?

Comment: can you please rewrite your question in more detail

Comment: Of course ! basically what i want is to control one relay from two different locations. One will be in the house(a panel with buttons) - where will be also this button for the relay. and will be controlled by atmega(when it will be pressed - will turn on the relay). and another "location" will be from the phone. but for this part i will use blynk and esp.

Comment: and you have the local part working and want to add the esp8266 with Blynk?

Comment: i use the pin from atmega as output. and on the breadboard is connected to relay(as signal) but on the same line(on the breadboard) i put also the pin from the esp. and the problem appears  that if i press the button - relay will turn on. but if i use the blynk app- nothing happens.

Comment: so for the moment i can control it using just atmega. if i remove the pin coming from the atmega - blynk works perfect.

Comment: so then read my answer again. the part about "read the esp8266 pin with ATmega"

Comment: so how should i do that? i mean.. the only solution i am thinking right now is to define another pin of atmega as INPUT and to read it.

Comment: is it a problem?

Comment: i am afraid it wont work.

Comment: why would it not work? this is what microcontrollers do

Comment: i've just try it and nothing. ..

Comment: it reads pin as high but only that

Comment: do you have a plain esp8266? what pin of the esp8266 did you use? (add the info to the question)

Comment: no, i have an NodeMCU and the pin used is D0 = GPIO 16

Comment: did you upload the Blynk sketch into the NodeMcu?

Comment: yes. Esp and blynk works perfect. The problem appears on the atmega side. even the relay module it goes crazy. Even if i set them in the setup function to be opend, when the sketch is uploaded, they close. and i cannot understand why.

Comment: i have tested what you told me to do on the arduino nano and i set the pin as input. if it's high, then the built in led will be on, else should be off. and works. it;s ok. but on the mega... something goes crazy.

Comment: anyway, you helped me. Thank you!

Comment: are the relays active LOW?

Comment: yes. if i set them as low - they are closed

Comment: something strange happening here.  i wrote a sketch to test one btn and if is high to turn the relay on. Ok...i uploaded the code and then if i press the button the atmega it sees that is high and execute 'digitalWrite(relay,HIGH); ' .the problem is that the relay wont close. i use dmm to measure the voltage at the relay signal pin and is 4.7V- normally it should close. but no. the led in front of the relay barely glows.

Comment: only pull-up on INPUT pin? not OUTPUT? check the pin numbers in sketch

Comment: now, if i test it using 2 conditions more - it works

Comment: i have posted the code above. so if i remove in the if statements  && and all after. it wont wok

Comment: `if (b == HIGH || a == LOW) {} else {}`?

Comment: i tested with your suggestion. this is what it happens. the led in front of relay(that who shows if the relay receive voltage) barely lights in both situations(if i use the app or i push the btn) BUT if i press the button and i use the app in the same time. the relay close.

Comment: it turns on and off fast?

Comment: no. if i press the button on blynk to turn it on. it wont turn on. instead the led glows (barely- like it receive the minimum voltage on the junction to let the current flows) but if i measure the voltage- there is 4.7V but the relay wont close.

Comment: Looking in the serial Monitor it looks like the relay will close only when it receive 0 but that is for LOW. and i set it to HIGH. My head hurts..don't know wtf is happening here. Very probably is that i had done something wrong.

Comment: has the button a pull-down resistor? it is better to wire the button to ground and use the internal pullup with INPUT_PULLUP mode like in DigitalInputPullup example